# Linux time command - real vs user vs system

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, executable-jar

I am running a jar file in Linux with time command. Below is the output after execution.

```
15454.58s real 123464.61s user  6455.55s system
```

Below is the command executed.

```
time java -jar -Xmx7168m Batch.jar
```

But actual time taken to execute the process is 9270 seconds.

Why the actual time(wall clock time) and real time is different?

Can anyone explain this? Its running on multi core machine (32 core).

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this explains the deviation you are experiencing. From the `time` [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_%28Unix%29):

> Because a program may fork children whose CPU times (both user and
>   sys) are added to the values reported by the time command, but on a
>   multicore system these tasks are run in parallel, the total CPU time
>   may be greater than the real time.

Apart from that, your understanding of real time conforms with the definition given in `time(7)`:

> Real  time  is  defined as time measured from some fixed point, either from a standard point in the past (see the description of the Epoch and calendar time below), or from some point (e.g., the start) in the life of a process (elapsed time).

See also `bash(1)` (although its documentation on the `time` command is not overly comprehensive).

If seconds are exact enough for you, this little wrapper can help:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

starttime=$( date +"%s" )
# run your program here
endtime=$( date +"%s" )

duration=$(( endtime-starttime ))
echo "Execution took ${duration} s."
```

Note: If the system time is changed while your program is running, the results will be incorrect.

Comment: So, is there a way to calculate the CPU time exactly using time command or any other ways?

Comment: @Shankar: You can simply compare time before and after execution - I've added that to my answer.

Comment: I have taken the execution time that is 9270 seconds, but i wanted to calculate CPU time as well, so that's why i used time command.. but the real time(execution time) returned by time command is 15454 seconds, its huge difference,so i cannot able to calculate CPU time properly.

Comment: The real question then is what do you mean by CPU time? If you mean system time, the system measurement from time in your original question includes the information about the system time for all (32) cores of your machine. A ballpark estimate could be obtained by dividing that with the number of cores that are being utilized during execution.

Comment: The CPU time is the combination of User time and System time.. right? Do you mean to say add system time and user time and divide by 32..is that CPU time?

Answer (score 0):

From what I remember, user time is the time it spends in user space, system is the time spend running in kernel space (syscalls, for example), and real is also called the wall clock time (the actual time that you can measure with a stop-watch, for example). Don't know exactly how this is calculated on a SMP system.